I have trouble Installing python3-debmutate Package, which is dependency for installing brz-debian_2.8.42_all.deb
For using build-deb.sh I need to install brz-debian_2.8.42_all.deb (this specific version).
python3-debmutate is dependency for it.
I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install the python3-debmutate package on my Ubuntu system. When attempting to install it using pip3, I receive the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-debmutate (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-debmutate

I attempted to clone the repository directly from GitHub (git clone https://github.com/example/python3-debmutate.git), but authentication failed due to changes in GitHub's authentication methods.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python Version: 3.8.10
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows of a workaround, I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions.
Thank you!

The error message you encountered suggests that this package name is not in the pypi index. The  package you are looking for is named debmutate on pypi. You can also check the availability on the pypi website.
To install this package use:
pip install debmutate
